# Flutterwave Rave Inline Checkout integration Error

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

I have tried the Flutterwave get paid button.
It returns the following error

```
"status":"error","message":"merchant public key required","data":null}
```

The code is below:

```
<form>
    <a class="flwpug_getpaid" data-PBFPubKey="FLWPUBK-MY PUBLIC KEY FROM DASHBOARD-X" data-txref="rave-123456" data-amount="10" data-customer_email="info@getset.com" data-currency="GHS" data-pay_button_text="Support Us Now" data-country="GH" data-redirect_url="https://your-website.com/urlredirect"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.ravepay.co/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/flwpbf-inline.js"></script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing the error because you didn't replace the data attribute value of data-PBFPubKey to your public key which can be found on your rave dashboard.

It looks like this:

> FLWPUBK-****************************-X

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate your flutter rave public key
https://dashboard.flutterwave.com/dashboard

And Also you need to key remember that which keys you are using 
for testing key you need to change your url also.
src - https://api.ravepay.co/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/flwpbf-inline.js" (For live keys)

change your script url to test script url: